# Bitcoin core txindex option - does it take argument or not?

Tags: bitcoin-core

`-txindex` is documented (in multiple places) to take no (numeric) argument and that "default: 0".

Does this mean that you have to say `-txindex=1` to set txindex, or does the mere appearance of `-txindex` on the command line set it to 1?

(IOW, is the value of the naked `-txindex` option 0 or 1?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my interpretation from looking at the code.

First, [`-txindex` is parsed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/5d132e8b974652d96466a1b73ec1231614719fe2/src/validation.cpp#L4147), defaulting to [`false` if it doesn't exist](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/214046f69b1978129030ba1f65007d57b29f0761/src/validation.h#L132).

The argument is to `-txindex` [interpreted as a boolean](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/37ffa16933953565dcab5c0d7e0ee1ebb6e349c3/src/util.cpp#L472), which assumes [no argument is the same as a true value](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/37ffa16933953565dcab5c0d7e0ee1ebb6e349c3/src/util.cpp#L388) (or else a non-zero argument is true).

So you do not need to provide an argument to `-txindex`, but if you do, it should be non-zero.

- Don't provide `-txindex`: don't index
- Provide `-txindex` with no argument: do index
- Provide `-txindex=0`: don't index
- Provide `-txindex=1` (or any other non-zero value): do index.

Comment: Thanks, it was `InterpretBool` I didn't find.